# Raspberry Pi bash script not functioning

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have a Raspberry Pi and I picked up a tft touch screen from adafruit to play around with. In order to get it working I've had to run a few lines from from rc.local including startx which for some reason has  logged me in as root@raspberrypi once the OS on the touchscreen starts working.

Once the OS is running on the touch screen, I need to run two programs, matchbox-keyboard and pianobar both of which run just fine by typing in "matchbox-keyboard", and "pianobar" from the LXTerminal.

However, if I try to add "matchbox-keyboard" or "pianobar" to rc.local under either the root rc.local or pi rc.local the programs will not run.

I tried to get around this by adding a file, keyboard.sh which I have given permissions to (chmod u+rwx keyboard.sh) to my desktop which has the lines:

```
#!bash
matchbox-keyboard
pianobar
```

The file is there, and when clicked asks me to either execute, or execute in terminal, both of which do not work.

I'm stumped.  Anyone have any Ideas?

Comment: I assume you cannot run X applications from the rc.local while X is not running. Those applications need X running before they can start.

Comment: Add the full path to those programs into the *.rc file, i.e. `/path/to/pianobar`, or update your PATH variable to include the correct path? Also running them in the background as mentioned below may help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how Debian is organized, but if `rc.local` is a file under `/etc/rc.d` the system will automatically run any commands from this file at the end of system initialization, so just filling the `rc.local` file with this would be enough (I'm supposing `matchbox-keyboard` is blocking, that's why I'm starting it on the background with the `&`):

```
matchbox-keyboard &
pianobar
```

Just the fact you have a `keyboard.sh` file at the `/etc/rc.d` dir doesn't mean it will get executed, even if it has `+x` permission. The file `rc.local` with exec permission, on the other hand, gets executed because it is run from `/etc/rc.d/rc.M` (I suppose it is like this on any Linux which uses BSD-style init scripts, like Slackware, for example).